# how can i get payment without payment method nonce?

Tags: c#, braintree

i need to get payment with Braintree and as far as i understand from the Braintree's documentation,followed the these steps;

1. created a Gateway

   ```
    BraintreeGateway Gateway = new BraintreeGateway
   {
       Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX,
       MerchantId = "xxxxxxxxxxx",
       PublicKey = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
       PrivateKey = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
   };
   ```
2. created a Customer

   ```
   var request = new CustomerRequest
   {
       FirstName = "firstName",
       LastName = "lastName",
       Email = "eMail",
       Phone = "phone",
   };
   string CustomerId = Gateway.Customer.Create(request).Target.Id;
   ```
3. created a credit card of the customer as using returened customerid

   ```
   var creditCardRequest = new CreditCardRequest
   {
       CustomerId = CustomerId,
       Number = "credit_card_number",
       ExpirationDate = "ex_date",
       CVV = "cc_cvv"
   };

   string creditCardToken = Gateway.CreditCard.Create(creditCardRequest).Target.Token;
   ```

what then? need a transaction with amount but the using what i found is not related with customer or credit card. Can someone help about what i should do next? Especially i need a method without 3d secure.

Comment: Are you aware that you included your merchant ID, public key, and private key? That's an **extremely bad idea** for what I hope are obvious reasons. I redacted them.

Comment: TBH, the question should be deleted and then re-added; people still have access to the keys from the OP... @Daniel Mann

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I flagged the post to see if moderators can expunge the revision history.

Comment: Of course i awared when i added my comment, it just to test as you can see the environment what i used is Sandbox, that means the informations are just for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of support:
To create a transaction, you must include an amount and either a paymentMethodNonce, a paymentMethodToken, or a customerId. Passing a customerId is equivalent to passing the paymentMethodToken of the customer's default payment method.

```
  TransactionRequest transactionRequest = new TransactionRequest()
    {
        Amount = amount,
        CustomerId = customer.Id,
        Options = new TransactionOptionsRequest
        {
            SubmitForSettlement = true
        }
    };

    Result<Transaction> result = Gateway.Transaction.Sale(transactionRequest);
```